# Display non Craft CMS data with Twig

Tags: templating, database

I have a Craft CMS installation in which there will be other data imported into the db (via Cronjob). It's data from a Weatherstation which will be displayed without further editing in the Control Panel.

Is it possible to display this data via Twig bypassing the Control Panel all-together?

something like:

```
{% for entry in special.db.section('xyz') %}
  {{ entry.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

My first thought would be to do this via the [Element API Plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) and then use JavaScript to display this data. But maybe that's not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom plugin to fetch the data. [Pluginfactory.io](http://pluginfactory.io/) is a good place to create your basic files/folders. Then you'll insert this function in your `PluginVariable`.

```
public function getData($table){
    return craft()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from($table)
        ->where('some Conditions)
        ->queryAll();
}
```

and in your template

```
{% for entry in craft.pluginName.getData('xyz') %}
    {{ entry.someField }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: this only works when the table prefix is the same as your craft tables. So before your `from($table)` Craft will automatically include a `$tablePrefix` (usually craft_) you can either name your custom tables `craft_` as well or change the prefix before your query

```
$oldPrefix = craft()->db->tablePrefix;
craft()->db->tablePrefix = '';
// handle your queries
craft()->db->tablePrefix = $oldPrefix;
```